# Streaming an in HTML embedded bokeh plot

Tags: python, streaming, bokeh

I am trying to embed a streaming bokeh plot into an HTML file using the autoload_server function:

```
from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.embed import autoload_server
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

data = dict(x=[], y=[])
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

plot = figure()
plot.circle(source=source, x='x', y='y')

counter = -1

def update_data():
    global xDate, yWind, counter
    counter += 1
    xDate = counter
    yWind = counter
    new_data_wind = dict(x=[xDate], y=[yWind])
    source.stream(new_data_wind, 300)

curdoc().add_root(plot)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update_data, 300)

session = push_session(curdoc())
script = autoload_server(plot, session_id=session.id)
print(script)
```

I basically start a bokeh server by using: "bokeh serve" and then run the code and insert the given script into an HTML file.

At first, no plot would be displayed, but after adding --allow-websocket-origin=localhost:63342 to the bokeh serve command, the page would show the plot grid, but no data is displayed.

Does someone have an idea as to why the data streaming function doesn't seem to work or what I can change to make the embedded plot stream the data?

I'm thankful for any further input, since I have yet to find some on the Internet.

**EDIT**
I've found the solution to my problem and will leave it here if anyone encounters something similar:

The code fragment:

```
session.loop_until_closed()
```

needs to be added to the end of the example above, so the session is looped and the final plot gets updated inside the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just post my answer as seen above, so this won't show up as unanswered question anymore:

The code fragment:

```
session.loop_until_closed()
```

needs to be added to the end of the example above, so the session is looped and the final plot gets updated inside the browser.